# Appcelerator Titanium Event Calendar

Tags: calendar, titanium, appcelerator

I am creating android app sdk is 1.7.5 and i want to add titanium event calendar to my app but I can't to do it! If someone knows or used please give me source code!
Thanks!

Comment: i used this code: http://pastie.org/3496926

Comment: but it worked wrong and without any events!

Comment: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.7.5/Titanium.Android.Calendar-module

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467468/how-to-add-event-in-calendar/9468233#9468233 see this post

Answer (score 0):

Titanium Appcelerator currently supports only Android Calendar module, that can be found here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Calendar.

If you need use Calendar in iOS, you can use this Open Source module, that implements Event Kit framework: https://github.com/Nyvra/TiEventKit.